# Rails: Converting from MongoMapper to Mongoid: Why can't I find models by :_id using Model.find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, mongomapper

On Rails 3.1 with Mongoid 2.4, BSON 1.5

I am having trouble finding a model by :_id using Mongoid's Model.find

Using where:

```
>> Athlete.where(:_id => BSON::ObjectId.from_string('4f2b22d70f67e90001001edd')).first
=> #<Athlete _id: 4f2b22d70f67e90001001edd, ...>
```

Using find:

```
>> Athlete.find('4f2b22d70f67e90001001edd')
=> nil
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually build your mongoid indexes:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```